# In angular I am routing to a different component route of the same module, url is changing but the view is not changing

Tags: angular, url, routes, angular6, angular-routing

I am new to angular, In angular 6 i m trying to route a component from another component, both the components belongs to the same module. The following code is changing the url but view is not changing.
Here is my html of first component componentA.html:

```
<div class="tp-content" routerLink="./details/{{tp.name}}"></div>
```

tp-component-routing.ts :

```
import { tpListComponent } from './tp-list/tp-list.component';
import { tpComponent } from './tp/tp.component';
import { DetailedInfoComponent } from './detailed-info/detailed-info.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'tp',
    component: tpComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'list',
            component: tpListComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'details/:id',
            component: DetailedInfoComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

];

```
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
```

})

```
export class tpRoutingModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DetailedInfoComponent } from './touchpoint/detailed-info/detailed-info.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/touchpoint/list', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: 'details/:id',component: DetailedInfoComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
   export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

URL is changing as tp/details/id along with this i want view of DetailedInfoComponent.

Comment: where is your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a `<router-outlet>`. Please add these to where you want to load both child components. ie in your case **`tpComponent.html`** :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: <router-outlet></router-outlet> is in app.component.html, if i'm keeping it in tpComponent.html too. first component is rendering twice & on click the second component is rendering after first component but i wanted it alone only on redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Joel is right. Where is your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
Routed view is rendered inside these tags.

Comment: <router-outlet></router-outlet> is in app.component.html, if i'm keeping it in tpComponent.html too. first component is rendering twice & on click the second component is rendering after first component but i wanted it alone only on redirection.

Comment: app.component.html only has <router-outlet>
</router-outlet>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
**app.component.ts**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**tp.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { tplist } from '../tp-list;
import { detailinfo } from '../detailinfo;
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ TplistComponent, DetailInfoComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
    ]
})
export class TpModule { }
```

**app-module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [
       tpModule
        ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/tslist',
    component: TpListComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '/detailInfo/:Id',
    component: DetailInfoComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

Comment: tpComponent is a module, inside that multiple components are there, so by default it is loading tpList, on click of tpList element i want to redirect to tpDetails Component.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not providing much detail about what exactly you want to achieve. Please read this article to achieve module level routing
https://medium.com/@astamataris/setting-up-routing-in-a-multi-module-angular-4-app-using-the-router-module-d8e610196443

Comment: you should not add route in both app-routing and module-routing. Please share the definition of your tp module. Blog share above will definitely help you

Comment: I have an app-componet.html which has the router-outlet tag only, then i hav tp-module inside which i have 2 components tp-component & tp-details component, Now i want to redirect from tp-component to tp-details component on click of tp-component element. relevant files with code i have already posted.

Comment: changed my answer, as per your feedback.If still not clear then please share for the components.